# Get program code on button click in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have designed a windows form, in which I have placed 3 buttons and a richtextBox.
Now I want to **get program code** in richtextbox on different button click, that I have written in click() event of each button.

**Example**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, ButtonEventArgs e)
{
       some code lines goes here   // 
       ....                        // All these lines to be displayed in richtextBox
       ....                        //
}
```

Comment: You want your program to print out the source, right? When you click a button?

Comment: This is called a quine. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753467/the-shortest-program-that-prints-its-own-source-code-in-c

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd have to actually link-to and read the source files to do this. Once your application is compiled your C# code becomes IL code and does not look the same at all.

Answer (score 0):

When you are executing it doesn't have the source anymore because its compiled into IL, if you want to display a string when the button is clicked then just do that.

```
richTextBox.Text = @"some code lines goes here...
...
...";
```